# I am 18. Do I have to list previous jobs before I was an adult?

Tags: resume

I had two jobs. Both of them had lots of criminal involvement in which I had to quit for my own safety. Do I have to list these? It looks pretty bad on a resume because my involvement with these small businesses was very short.

Comment: Unless those jobs were on the lines "professional window smasher" or "lookout for carjacking crew", how is anyone going to know there was "criminal involvement"? Or are you saying that these businesses would be "known" to have a criminal element (certain bars or clubs, for example).

Answer (score 7):

You should only put things on your resume that would help you get a job.  If your previous jobs would help, add them.  If they don't help or raise red flags for sure don't add them.  You are 18 so there is no expectation either way.

Answer (score 4):

No.  You are 18.  It is not uncommon for someone your age to have little to no work experience.  You may want to think about what sorts of things you CAN put on your resume though.  You want to display anything that shows work ethic, ability to learn, and good character (e.g., volunteer work, sports and clubs, etc.).

And since your last two jobs have involved criminal activity, you may want to look into the background of your next employer before you accept any offers.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. I've seen job application forms that include a section that states something like "list **all** previous employment", and includes fine print like "any omission can result in loss of a job offer or termination of employment". In such a situation, if you left off those two positions, and they discovered the truth, you could technically lose your job as a result.

Is it likely? Again, it depends. Many companies run an employment or background check prior to offering you the position. If you were paid via a standard 1099 or W-2, they may be able to discover it fairly easily. If you were paid under the table, it might be harder (though still not impossible).

You'll have to weigh the advantages and disadvantages of listing a position that's criminally connected versus intentionally submitting an incomplete job history.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks pretty bad on a resume because my involvement with these small businesses was very short.

Assuming you are in the US, then the legal age to work is 16 (I think you can go to work at age 14 in some areas) but you have at most 2 years of time to work. Most people would expect you to be part time since you're going to school and possibly be working during summer or weekends. So reality working someplace for 2-4 at age 16-22 doesn't sound bad at all assuming you are in school.

If you ever won an award such as employee of the month at any of these locations be sure to list them but otherwise I wouldn't list them under 18.